# What to replace <span> in <form> with? "In XHTML 1.1 the tag <form> cannot contain tag <span>

Tags: html, xhtml, authentication

I am a beginner in html. I am using a login module from yootools:

What to replace `<span>` in  with? I have XHTML 1.1 strict doctype (changing transitional fixes it) and I get error:

"In XHTML 1.1 the tag `<form>` cannot contain tag `<span>`

This is user/pass box lined up next to each other on the same line. What can I replace these spans with so it doesnt complain?

Thanks!

Maria

Edit: Cleaned up to this now. So I just need to find a way to replace `<span class="username">` with something.

```
<li class="login">
    <form action="/cgi-bin/login" method="post" name="Login">

        <span class="username">
        <input type="text" name="username" size="18"  value="Username"  />
        </span>

        <span class="password">
        <input type="password" name="passwd" size="10" value="Password" />
        </span>

        <span class="login-button">
        <button value="Login" name="Submit" type="submit" title="L">L</button>
        </span>

    </form>
</li>





a:focus { outline: none; }

span.username,
span.password {
    width: 74px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 6px 5px 2px 25px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 0px; 

}



span.username input,
span.password input {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    color: #646464;
    font-size: 11px;
}



span.login-button {
    margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}



span.login-button button {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #646464;
}




.login {
    float:right; 
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;

}


.login span.username {
    background: url(img/username_bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat; /* ie6png:crop */
}

.login span.password {
    background: url(img/password_bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat; /* ie6png:crop */
}

.login span.username:hover {
    background: url(img/username_bg.png) 0 -24px no-repeat;
}

.login span.password:hover {
    background: url(img/password_bg.png) 0 -24px no-repeat;
}



.login span.username input:hover,
.login span.password input:hover,
.login span.username input:focus,
.login span.password input:focus {
    color: #F2AD29;
}

.login span.login-button {
    background: url(img/button_bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat; /* ie6png:crop */
}

.login span.login-button:hover {
    background: url(img/button_bg.png) 0 -20px no-repeat;
}



.login span.login-button button:hover {
    color: #F2AD29;
}
```

Comment: Maria, you dont have enough reputation to upvote yet, but you should Accept the answer that most closely matches your specific answer, in this case Alochi answered the same as me first, so best to accept that answer.

Comment: How do I do that Mauro? I tried upvoting, didnt work as you said. I don't see any 'Accept this answer'.

Comment: Maria, just find the answer and hover over the greyed out checkmark so it appears green and click it.

Answer (score 3):

In the schema http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd

The Form Tag can only contain block elements, try this instead:

```
<li class="login"> 
    <form action="/cgi-bin/login" method="post" name="Login"> 
        <div>
        <span class="username"> 
        <input type="text" name="username" size="18"  value="Username"  /> 
        </span> 

        <span class="password"> 
        <input type="password" name="passwd" size="10" value="Password" /> 
        </span> 

        <span class="login-button"> 
        <button value="Login" name="Submit" type="submit" title="L">L</button> 
        </span> 
        </div>     
    </form> 
</li>
```

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssss Mauro! God Bless you!

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `<div>` tag immediately after the `<form>` tag and a `</div>` tag immediately before the `</form>` tag, and you wont need to change your spans at all.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssss Alochi! God Bless you!

Comment: This place is spectacular! I asked 3 questions, everytime somebody saved me from so much time. And every time I asked the question after spending 6 hours searching and trying! You people are such experts.

Alochi, Mario, Dori, MatrixFrog... thank you all so very much. I there a community donation or something like this here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only difference between having those spans and not having them is that spans are automatically displayed inline, while divs and many other elements (like inputs) are automatically displayed "block." So try just adding `display : inline;` to the CSS for the two text fields.

Comment: Thanks. That i know. But what can i replace all these span classes with? They do different formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<li class="login-black">
    <form action="/cgi-bin/login" method="post" name="Login">
        <input type="text" name="username" size="10" value="Username" class="username niftyquick y-login login" />
        <input type="password" name="passwd" size="10" value="Password" class="password niftyquick y-login login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="yes" />
        <button value="Login" name="Submit" type="submit" title="L" class="login-button niftyquick y-login login">Log</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

If your `spans` are only there for styling, apply those classes to the elements themselves instead.

Comment: Dori, I cleaned up the original post, dont need so many spans now.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Furthermore, now I get "in XHTML 1.1, tag <form> cannot contain tag <input>" !!! What is form there for if no input???