# form onsubmit not called with multiple spans each containing an input

Tags: html

works:

```
<form class=filter onsubmit="alert('submit');">
    <span class=a></span>
    <span class=b> <input type=text name=b /> </span>
</form>
```

doesn't work:

```
<form class=filter onsubmit="alert('submit');">
    <span class=a></span>
    <span class=b> <input type=text name=b /> </span>
    <span class=c> <input type=text name=c /> </span>
</form>
```

By work, I mean that when I type in text and hit enter, the form onsubmit is called (a simple alert). Why doesn't it fire in the second case? What is the best way to fix it or get around it? I could put a separate onchange event on each input in the html, or add the events through javascript/JQuery. Is that the best approach?

---

*I've got a "table" built from divs for rows and spans for entries. The form is one row in the table. Wrapping the inputs inside spans makes the formatting (mainly column widths/spacing) more uniform. Then the actual input element is set to 80% of the span width.*

Comment: I tried adding a div around the spans inside the form (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572104/what-to-replace-span-in-form-with-in-xhtml-1-1-the-tag-form-cannot-conta) without success.

Comment: The problem lies simply in _multiple inputs without a submit_. Don't assume that it has to do with `spans`. Keep an open mind :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should really wrap your attribute values in `""`s.
2. Depending on the browser, the Enter key may only cause a form submission if the form has exactly one text field, or only when there is a submit button present. To get around this you could try the above with a hidden `input type="submit"`, or use a combination of jQuery's [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) and [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to detect an `enter` keypress and submit the form programmatically.

   - [How to detect pressing Enter on keyboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979662/how-to-detect-pressing-enter-on-keyboard-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd tested it without the spans but you're right, it's not the spans that cause the onsubmit not to fire on enter but having multiple inputs at all.

Comment: When I made the submit button hidden, it no longer triggers the onsubmit. I'll just use some js, thanks.

Comment: Oh, and how come wrap the values in quotes? If it makes any difference... the site is html5 and I have 6 users who use modern browsers (or whatever I tell them to use).

Comment: @jmilloy It is required by XHTML spec, not required for HTML5 simple attribute values, but highly [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes). For a college security course I wrote a website virus that used lack-of-quotes as an entry point.

Comment: @paislee is your second point (forms w/ multiple input elements must have an, optionally hidden, `<input type="submit" />` element) a documented part of the HTML/5 spec?  I can confirm it works (thanks), though I can't think of why it would be required.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your input button for submitting?

I just tried this in [jsfiddle and it worked](http://jsfiddle.net/Scorpionb/bbfQV/):

```
<form class=filter onsubmit="alert('submit');">
    <span class=a></span>
    <span class=b> <input type=text name=b /> </span>
    <span class=c> <input type=text name=c /> </span>
    <input type='submit' />
</form>​
```

Comment: Okay. I don't want a submit button, I want to submit the form after hitting enter in any of the fields.